# Is shared_future<void> a legitimate replacement for a condition_variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Josuttis states ["Standard Library", 2nd ed, pg 1003]:

> Futures allow you to block until data by another thread is provided or another thread is done. However, a future can pass data from one thread to another only once. In fact, a future's major purpose is to deal with return values or exceptions of threads.

On the other hand, a `shared_future<void>` can be used by *multiple* threads, to identify when another thread has done its job.

Also, in general, high-level concurrency features (such as `future`s) should be preferred to low-level ones (such as `condition_variable`s).

Therefore, I'd like to ask: Is there any situation (requiring synchronization of multiple threads) in which a `shared_future<void>` won't suffice and a `condition_variable` is essential?

Comment: Start from the fact that only one of these two is reusable.

Comment: @T.C., could you kindly explain your comment? Thanks.

Comment: Imagine a thread that produces data multiple times. You can `notify_all` on a condition variable multiple times. On the other hand, you can set the result on a future only once (then, you would need to distribute another future to wait on for the next result each time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments by @T.C. and @hlt, the use of `future`s/`shared_future`s is mostly limited in the sense that they can only be used once. So for every communication task you have to have a new `future`. The pros and cons are nicely explained by Scott Meyers in:

> Item 39: Consider void futures for **one-shot** event
> communication.
> *Scott Meyers: Effective Modern C++ (emphasis mine)*

His conclusion is that using `promise`/`future` pairs dodges many of the problems with the use of `condidition_variable`s, providing a nicer way of communicating **one-shot** events. The price to pay is that you are using dynamically allocated memory for the shared states and more importantly, that you have to have one `promise`/`future` pair for every event that you want to communicate.

Answer (score 3):

While the notion of using high-level abstracts instead of low-level abstract is laudable, there is a misconception here. `std::future` is not a high-level replacement for `std::conditional_variable`. Instead, it is a specific high-level construct build for a specific use-case of `std::condition_variable` - namely, a one-time return of the value.

Obviously, not all uses of condition variable is for this scenario. For example, an message queue can not be implemented with `std::future`, no matter how much you try. Such a thread is another high-level construct built on low-level building block. So yes, shoot for high-level constructs, but do not expect a one-to-one map mapping between high and low level.